# Error message PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\Domain\Currency\Exception\CurrencyConstraintException code 14 while trying to duplicate a product

Tags: database, prestashop

Started getting this error randomly after migrating to Prestashop 8. We have all of our prices set in PLN - we do have other currencies as we're planning to expand (EUR, USD, GBP), however they're all disabled right now. What's weirder is that it happens on completely random products, even if they were published minutes apart in the same batch.

I've noticed that the PLN currency has ID 2 which made me assume this was the issue - it had ID 1 on our old store as it is the default one and we only started adding new languages and currencies after migrating. The comment in the file says "When currency id value is invalid" which would confirm that, however I've tried removing the other currencies and then manually changing the ID to 1 in the currency and currency_lang tables. It did not fix the issue.
I also checked the ISO codes in the supplementalData.xml file but they all seem correct.